# Super Blox - level 1.8

Tags: combinatorics, video-games

I wrote a free puzzle game for Android phones, called [Super Blox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xyz.iaptest&hl=en_AU). The aim of each level is to change the colour of all blue blocks (squares) to green using the following rules:

- You can move any block or the red ball to an adjacent empty location (horizontally or vertically, but not diagonally).
- Once the red ball touches any blue blocks it instantly turns them green. This can happen to multiple blocks in one move.
- The blocks and the ball cannot leave the boundary of the level (black rectangle).

Here is an interesting level from the game. Can you solve it in 12 moves?

[image]

Comment: When you say "to an adjacent empty location" you're allowing (form the position pictued) moving the red ball to the left so it abuts the sixth block, or the sixth block to the right so it abuts the ball? If not, then I don't understand how by moving things to empty locations you get the ball and any block to touch one another.

Comment: What size grid does the above image depict? Is it 4x3 or 7x5?

Comment: @msh the blocks are the blue squares. You can move the ball to the 6th column and it will touch the block in the 5th column. You can also move the block in the 5th column to the right and it will touch the ball.

Comment: @shoover it is 7x5.

Comment: Yeah, that's what was unclear. It looks like a $4\times3$ grid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one solution for 12 moves

> First, move the top right blue square one square right and one square down.  Then move the bottom left blue square one square right.  Then move the red square left, down, left four times, and up three times.
>
>  [image]

Comment: You beat me to it by 31 seconds! And using very similar aesthetics ;) well done, +1

Comment: Well done! You got it, by less than a minute.

Answer (score 8):

The solution:

> First, we rearrange three blue blocks using 3 steps
>  Then we take a path of 9 steps with the red ball
>  [image]

Comment: Correct! Just missed out on the tick. But stay tuned for more puzzles of this type :)